# What is the distance of a corner of a triangle to the opposite side?

Tags: trigonometry, terminology, simplex

The **altitudes** of a triangle are the distances of its corners to the respective lines containing the opposite sides.

Is there a name for the distances of its corners to the opposite sides themselves?

I call them **restricted altitudes** for the time being. If, for instance, we consider an isosceles triangle where the apex approaches the base, we see that the altitude and restricted altitude for some corners may sometimes have the same length, whereas they differ for other corners.

If they have a name in the literature, then I'd be interested about results on those restricted altitudes. More generally, I am interested in the higher dimensional case.

Comment: In other words, the "restricted altitude" is either the (usual) altitude or the shorter of the two adjacent sides, depending on whether the line through the corner that's perpendicular to the line containing the opposite side intersects the opposite side? I don't know of a name for this